# How to enable Localstack Kinesis Data Streams to capture Dynamodb changes from InMemory DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, localstack, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to process the DynamoDB changes using Kinesis Data Streams in my local. I am using the Localstack to spin up both DynamoDB and Kinesis in my local. Which is working as expected but sometimes, the Localstack DynamoDB slows down. This is a known issue as per this discussion in the Localstack forum:
https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1205

So, I am planning to make use of DynamoDB local which is InMemory database. But when I am trying to enable the Kinesis Data Stream which is running on Localstack the InMemory database is not able to communicate with the Localstack Kinesis service and it throws the resource not found exception.

Can somebody help me on this?